# Improving speed while iterating over ~400k XML files

Tags: python, xml, performance, loops, optimization

This is more of a theoretical question to understand objects, garbage collection and performance of Python better.

Lets say i have a ton of XML files and want to iterate over each one, get all the tags, store them in a dict, increase counters for each tag etc. When i do this, the first, lets say 15k iterations, process really quick but afterwards the script slows down significantly, while the memory usage, CPU load etc. are fine. Why is that? Do i write hidden objects each iteration which are not cleaned up, can i do something to improve it? I tried to use regex instead of ElementTree but it wasnt worth the effort since i only want to extract first level tags and it would make it more complex.

Unfortunately i cannot give a reproducible example without providing the XML files, however this is my code:

```
import os
import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

original_implemented_tags = os.path.abspath("/path/to/file")

required_tags = {}
optional_tags = {}
new_tags = {}

# read original tags
for _ in open(original_implemented_tags, "r"):
    if "@XmlElement(name =" in _:
        _xml_attr = _.split('"')[1]
        if "required = true" in _:
            required_tags[_xml_attr] = 1  # i set this to 1 so i can use if dict.get(_xml_attr) (0 returns False)
        else:
            optional_tags[_xml_attr] = 1

# read all XML files from nested folder containing XML dumps and other files
clinical_trial_root_dir = os.path.abspath("/path/to/dump/folder")
xml_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(clinical_trial_root_dir):
    xml_files.extend([os.path.join(root, _) for _ in files if os.path.splitext(_)[-1] == '.xml'])


# function for parsing a file and extract unique tags
def read_via_etree(file):
    _root = ElementTree.parse(file).getroot()
    _main_tags = list(set([_.tag for _ in _root.findall("./")]))  # some tags occur twice
    for _attr in _main_tags:
        # if tag doesnt exist in original document, increase counts in new_tags
        if _attr not in required_tags.keys() and _attr not in optional_tags.keys():
            if _attr not in new_tags.keys():
                new_tags[_attr] = 1
            else:
                new_tags[_attr] += 1

        # otherwise, increase counts in either one of required_tags or optional_tags
        if required_tags.get(_attr):
            required_tags[_attr] += 1
        if optional_tags.get(_attr):
            optional_tags[_attr] += 1


# actual parsing with indicator
for idx, xml in enumerate(xml_files):
    if idx % 1000 == 0:
        print(f"Analyzed {idx} files")
    read_via_etree(xml)

# undoing the initial 1
for k in required_tags.keys():
    required_tags[k] -= 1

for k in optional_tags.keys():
    optional_tags[k] -= 1

print(f"Done parsing {len(xml_files)} documents in {datetime.datetime.now() - start_time}")
```

---

Example of one XML file:

```
<parent_element>
  <tag_i_need>
    <tag_i_dont_need>Some text i dont need</tag_i_dont_need>
  </tag_i_need>
  <another_tag_i_need>Some text i also dont need</another_tag_i_need>
</parent_element>
```

Comment: "i only want to extract first level tags" - Does this mean that you are only interested in the root element of each XML file?

Comment: @mzjn yes - each XML file contains one parent element which name does not interest me, and can only contain one of such

Comment: If the apparent slow-down was due to Python failing to "clean up" then surely you'd expect to see RAM usage gradually increase yet you say that that's not a problem. How do you know (from the code shown) that it's slowing down?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein thank you - i thought so. I see it only via the line `print(f"Analyzed {idx} files")` - could add some indication there how much time passed since the last 1k documents, but i can clearly see that this prints happen really fast for the first 10k files and slows down afterwards

Comment: Then what does interest you? I have no idea what your code is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Did you try to profile the performance of the code and look for bottlenecks?

Comment: @mzjn i want to check if all XML files have the tags i expect them to, but that is not really the point of my question - i want to know if i can do something to optimize the parsing of so many files

Comment: @mnikley Don't forget that the standard output stream is buffered. As you suggest, add some interval timing code and also make sure you flush stdout after the print

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks for your idea, and no i havent - you mean with `cProfile` for example?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein thanks - that sounds like a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

After the helpful comments i added a timestamp to my loop indicating how much time is passed since the last 1k documents and flushed the sys.stdout:

```
import sys

loop_timer = datetime.datetime.now()
for idx, xml in enumerate(xml_files):
    if idx % 1000 == 0:
        print(f"Analyzed {idx} files in {datetime.datetime.now() - loop_timer}")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        loop_timer = datetime.datetime.now()
    read_via_etree(xml)
```

I think it makes sense now since the XML files vary in size, and due the fact that the standard output stream is buffered. Thanks to [Albert Winestein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17580381/albert-winestein)